# How can read/write to my ACR122U NFC/Smartcard reader?

Tags: nfc, smartcard-reader, acr122

I bought a GoToTags ACR122U NFC/smartcard reader but I am really disappointed with it. Their free windows application simply locks you into their propietary stuff. I want to write my own application to read/write NFC tags.

I have been trying to find an SDK that I can use with managed code (C#) but no luck yet. Somewhere I found ACR122U sample applications with "SDK" but none of the sample apps work because NONE has a reference to a DLL that can be used to access it. Only their C++ code seems to have an acr122.dll in their root directory but it is not possible to import it as a reference in my C# application.

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for lies here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15599119/1329396

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is SDK for NFC reader/writer acr122u device required to build read/write application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453709/is-sdk-for-nfc-reader-writer-acr122u-device-required-to-build-read-write-applica)